# Are JavaScript List Operations Synchronous?

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous

So I've been doing some research into how JavaScript is actually single threaded even though it appears to be multithreaded (or at least that's how I understand it), and I was wondering if the following function would be guaranteed to complete before some other function is called.

I'm fairly certain that it is, but the call to `push()` makes me worry that when it is called, some other function may execute first. That being said, I can't think of any sort of long running code that would be ran in `push()`.

```
// adds a new node to children, after checking if its UID is not in childrenAdded
this.addChild = function(newChild) {
    if (!_this._childrenAdded[newChild.uid]) {
        _this._childrenAdded[newChild.uid] = true;            
        _this._children.push(newChild);
    }
}
```

Comment: We have no idea what `_this` is, or how `this.addChild` is called, but the rest of the code, accessing members with brackets and pushing to an array, is most certainly **synchronous**. Basically, only timers, ajax and other requests are asynchronous in clientside JS

Comment: There is nothing asynchronous with that code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) methods, including `push`, are synchronous. That's pretty much the default for all operations in JS, asynchronous is the exception and documented in every such function.

Answer (score 1):

If a function is asynchronous, it will usually take a callback function as parameter, or return a `Promise` or something of that kind.

That way you'll always be able to make sure, your code executes after the function has terminated, if that is what you want.

So to answer your question: push is synchronous! :)

Comment: "If a function is asynchronous, it will usually take a callback function as parameter" — This is not a good indicator. For example, `Array.prototype.sort` and `Array.prototype.forEach` both take functions as arguments but are synchronous.

Comment: yeah, but if you take a look at any kind of documentation or just generally figure out how these functions work (which you'll have to do, to use them), you'll know, that these function parameters aren't callbacks and have a completely different purpose. I didn't say "whenever a function is parsed as a parameter, it is a callback function" ;)

Answer (score 1):

Everything in Javascript is synchronous.  It might behave and look asynchronous, but that's because everything in javascript is put in an execution stack.  Once something is finished, it's popped off the stack.

If you have an event, it's pushed into an event loop.  Once everything is popped off the execution stack, it searches the event loop to see if it has anything to run.  If it does, then it will run that event.  It might look asynchronous, but it's really not.

So, in conclusion.  Javascript is synchronous.

Answer (score 0):

The Array push method is synchronous. I highly recommend watching [this video on the javascript event loop](https://youtu.be/8aGhZQkoFbQ) to understand what goes on behind the scenes.

If you watch it enough times, it should clarify how the "single threaded even though it appears to be multithreaded" part of javascript works. Or maybe it might confuse you more, but hey that's javascript for you!